# Free commandline CD/DVD burner for Windows working without installation

Tags: windows, command-line, burning, dvd-burning

I'm looking for a freeware CD/DVD, command-line burner for Windows without installation requirement. Found CommandBurner, but unfortunately it needs to be installed. Is there any portable alternative?

Answer (score 2):

CreateCD: [link](http://isorecorder.alexfeinman.com/CreateCD.htm) Does CDs only though.

There is also a utility called *dvdburn.exe*. It comes with the resource kit for Win2003 and WinXP.