# Batch File to Send Zip File to CD/DVD drive

Tags: batch-file, dvd-burning, cd-burning

I have written a batch file which creates a Zip from a set of files. This works fine.

I would now like to extend this batch file so the outputted zip file (from the above batch file) is written to a DVD/CD.

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Write a DVD from the Windows Command Line](http://superuser.com/questions/110823/write-a-dvd-from-the-windows-command-line) also see: [Free commandline CD/DVD burner for Windows working without installation](http://superuser.com/questions/197082/free-commandline-cd-dvd-burner-for-windows-working-without-installation)

Comment: @Techie007-Thanks for highlighting these questions. I would like to know whether this task can be completed without installing further Windows resource kits or third party applications. The reason being that I cannot install software on this machine.

Comment: No, there's no CD/DVD burning command-line utility included with Windows. But really, just download the resource kit to a computer you CAN install stuff on, install it, and copy the burning utility's EXE over to the other computer and run it; it doesn't actually need to be "installed" on the computer.